# Having issues assigning labels to image data

Tags: python, tensorflow

``The directory that the data is in only has 50 files but after assigning images labels and resizing when i print the len of data i get 750. I am starting to wonder if the arrays within the images are being separated and assigned their own label.[code where images are given a label and resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6fi1.png)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import random
Directory='../input/hotdog'
Directory1='../input/nothotdog'
image_size=100
data=[]
for directory in Directory:
    folder=os.path.join(Directory)
    label=0 
    for img in os.listdir(Directory):
        img_path=os.path.join(Directory, img)
        img_arr= cv2.imread(img_path)
        img_arr= cv2.resize(img_arr, dsize=(image_size, image_size))
        data.append([img_arr, label])
print(len(data))
for directory in Directory1:
    folder=os.path.join(Directory1)
    label=1 
    for img in os.listdir(Directory1):
        img_path=os.path.join(Directory1, img)
        img_arr= cv2.imread(img_path)
        img_arr= cv2.resize(img_arr, dsize=(image_size, image_size))
        data.append([img_arr, label])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: what is inside Directory? Can you post the code instead of Image?

Comment: Hey i posted my code sorry about the inconvinience

Comment: the directory consists of 50 image files each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```py
for directory in Directory:
```

loops over the charactes in `Directory` which is `'../input/hotdog'`.

You should remove the `for` loop alltogether:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import random
Directory='../input/hotdog'
Directory1='../input/nothotdog'
image_size=100
data=[]

label=0
for img in os.listdir(Directory):
    img_path=os.path.join(Directory, img)
    img_arr= cv2.imread(img_path)
    img_arr= cv2.resize(img_arr, dsize=(image_size, image_size))
    data.append([img_arr, label])

print(len(data))

label=1
for img in os.listdir(Directory1):
    img_path=os.path.join(Directory1, img)
    img_arr= cv2.imread(img_path)
    img_arr= cv2.resize(img_arr, dsize=(image_size, image_size))
    data.append([img_arr, label])
```